# PHP/AJAX application label won't load

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I have an ajax/php application which you can download from dropbox.
it's here:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zkca8peed97ieiu/AABwKVf_vP6s0BnQpxCcAeWZa?dl=0

the HTML code is rendered but the div tag isn't as I think the page is not interactive because the javascript file foodstore.js won't render.

Does anyone know any fixes?
The app should when typed in tell you whether the current product is in stock or not with the div tag underInput.

Here's the javascript then HTML,

```js
//Create object that's responsible for communicating with server behind the scenes.
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject(); //a function name which is to be built now.


//awesome object which allows you to communicate with server without having to
//refresh the page.

function createXMLHttpRequestObjecct() {
    
    var xmlHttp;
    
    //work for IE!
    if(window.ActiveXobject){
        try {
            
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
        
    } else { //work for other browsers
        
        try {
         xmlHttp =  new XMLHttpRequest(); //built-in function doesn't need to be coded itself. 
        }catch(e) {
            xmlHttp= false;
        }
        
    }
    if(!xmlHttp)
        alert("Unfortunately we cannot create the object");
    else 
        return xmlHttp; //function needs return statement otherwise variable won't equal anything
}

/*----------------------------------------SAMPLE CODE FOR EVERY AJAX PROGRAMME ABOVE -------------------------------*/

//Heart of being able to communicate to the server with ajax.
function process() {
    //this process function is responsible for taking the object created above
    //and sending the request to the server
    //xmlhttp is the object we are testing for.
    //if 0 and 4 it means the object is free and ready to communicate with server
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4) {
        food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementbyId("userInput").value);//document is webpage .value
        //is the value that the user types into the input box.
        
        //build-in function to communicate with the server
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "foodstore.php?food="+food,true);//creates request to send to the server.
        //As php accepts info one of two ways ie GET and POST
        //false/true if ajax request should be done asynchronously as in without refreshing the page.
        //.open function creates the type of reqeust that we want. 
        
        //Communicate with the webserver
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        
        //Send to the server
        xmlHttp.send(null); //the parameter used is only used with post. we are using get, that's why it's null.
        
         }else {
            setTimeout('process()',1000); //is object ready to communicate or busy.
            //if busy wait and try again.
       
    }
}

function handleServerResponse() {
    //Server will send an XML file in between the <response> tags.
    //first we check object for errors.
    
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)  {//state no.4 when object is done communicating with the server
        if (xmlHttp.status==200) { //200 means that communication went okay with the server.
            
            xmlResponse=xmlHttp.responseXML;  //extracting xml from foodstore.php so the
            //xml response is basically the new xml.
            
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;//documentelement is the root 
            //element of the xml file. the document element is where we pull everythin else
            //from.
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data; //.data gets data from xml file
            //gets the message from the server, in between the response tags.
            
            //Set the inner html, part that shows to the user equals to a blue color messag.e
            document.getElementbyId("underInput").innerHTMl = '<span style="color:blue">' + message + '</span>'; //innerHTML is html inbetween the div
            ///the stuff that shows on the webpage.
            setTimeOut('process()',1000);
        } else {
            
            alert("Something went wrong!");
        }
        
    }
    
}
//STEPS:
//1. Creates the object for communication
//2. Communicatse with the server
//3. Update your webpage, create an element or do something cool
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="foodstore.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body onload="process()"> <!--Function will be inside javascript and will kickstart ajax programme. -->
        
        <h3>The Chuff Bucket</h3>
        <p>Enter the food you would like to order:</p>
        <input type="text" id="userInput"/>
        <div id="underInput"> 
        </div>
        
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

and here's the PHP file from the project file , it's foodstore.php

```
    <?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

header('Content-Type: text/xml'); //we're going to be generating xml content.
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';
$food = $_GET['food'];  //store user data in this variable. 
                        //can send things to PHP in one of two ways using either get or post.
                        //we use get because it's more simple.
$foodArray = array('tuna','bacon','beef','loaf','ham');
if(in_array($food,$foodArray))//takes two params. name of variable and the array itself.
        echo 'We do have '.$food.'!';           
elseif($food=='')
    echo'Enter a food you idiot';
else
    echo'Sorry we have none of '.$food.'in stock!';


echo '</response>';
?>
```

And basically when you type something in it should tell you whether that item is in stock or not. It won't do that and I can't quite understand why.

I have double checked that the code is typed in correctly. Have I made any syntax errors?
Kind regards,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [provide an example to your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [avoid linking to external resources](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for the question.

Comment: The div tag isn't being rendered as when something is typed in, a result saying "yes we do have it in stock" or no we don't isn't shown. I've seen many links to jsfiddle, that's why I thought I could provide a link to dropbox.

Comment: Okay, a couple of quick points - but not a solution. JS is case-sensitive. Therefore, `document.getElementbyId` and `setTimeOut` are both failing in `foodstore.js` - they should be `document.getElementById` and `setTimeout`. Next, not only is `createXmlHttpRequestObject` spelled two different ways (one of them has .....Objecct, the other .....Object) but also one has a capitalized `XML` while the other has `Xml`. Fixing these errors will get rid of errors in the console (Hope you're using it, Ctrl-Shift-I for Chrome)

Comment: does the applet run though once these bugs are fixed? Or is there a major bug I'm yet to spot?